# Fix pgadmin SQL editor screen after resizing

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

This has happened to me a few times and it's annoying, whenever I take my laptop home my pgadmin editor stops working after resizing (I have more screens at work):

[image]

I have tried everything possible and the editor does not regain its correct shape and the "edit" area is impossible to get.
If you don't know the answer, do you have any suggestions for a good free SQL editor, now that we all know pgadmin is horrible...

Comment: It is not pgAdmin bug. There is the splitter between tabs (Data output, Explain,..) and main menu. Just drag it to bottom. After window size changed the result's part takes whole space of the client area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does get frustrating at times, especially when the monitor configurations are different at different places (say office vs home). So although one configuration works in office, when you take the laptop home, the Edit area is effectively missing, and the output window is at 100%.

You didn't mention the OS, but on windows I used to first Un-maximize the window, and then use to Right-Click on the Window (blue?) bar, that gave me the default MS Windows options (Move, Minimize, Maximize, Restore etc.). (These have been life-savers also when a window is completely out of the visible scope).

Once the menu is selected (nowadays using special keyboard combinations, i.e. a mouse isn't required), you could take the window further up and start to see a very small Query box open up. That way, you can now select the section divider and slide it down to reduce the Output Window size.

Painful, but worked most of the times.